# Can anyone suggest tutorial for creating own Magento theme?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, custom, create

I searched the web to find any tutorial which guides step by step to create a custom theme. Basically what I expect is to `convert a HTML and CSS code to a Magento theme.` But still couldn't find a proper tutorial or a book. Can anyone suggest the relevant resources please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you go on Youtube as there is a ton of sruff there!

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the designer guide on [this Magento page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide) and also check out [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/magento-for-designers-part-3/) starting from part 3. (prt 1&2 are installation etc). For me as a backend developer these 2 were very helpful in getting some insight in how templating works.

**[EDIT]** To implement a static html file to a theme you will first need to define which template or PHTML files hold which parts. For this you can use the Magento Template hints or [Aoe TemplateHits](https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_TemplateHints) (I'd suggest using the last one).

This way you can find the file to put your header in, menus, product blocks etc. Then copy each block that you want to edit from the `base/default` template folter to your own template and customise them.

In the skins directory of your template copy the `styles.css` from the `default/blank` theme as it is a nice start of point from where you can add your own CSS.

I don't know any tutorial that outlines this better but these are basically the steps you need to take.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But these doesn't contain practical examples for creating a custom theme. Instead they contains lot of theory which I already know.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: @Su123 did you manage to resolve the issue with the extra info?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and +1, At the same time I found an E-book which guides as I expected. http://www.scribd.com/doc/51136713/designing-for-magento